# Debug kernel crash with netconsole

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, crash

Recently I face the kernel crash problem.

After googling, I try to use netconsole to dump the kernel message to another computer.

But the log prints too fast, it seems that netconsole cannot dump all the message to another computer in real-time.

Since on the crashed computer, I cannot see any oops message, so I cannot use gdb to debug neither.

Are there any better ways to debug with kernel crash?

Thanks

Comment: Is it possible to use serial interface?

Comment: I haven't tried this approach, and will give a try.